# Coping with an evil omnipotent being?

Tags: characters

How do I make a average person be able to cope with being tortured by a omnipotent being? I want to have an omnipotent villain, and a non omnipotent protagonist. I want it to be about how a normal person deal with an omnipotent being who is evil, sadistic and likes to take away everything the person can use to make themselves feel better. How can I make the human protagonist realistically deal with an evil villain who can literally do anything at all?

Comment: Is the villain able to manipulate the thoughts of the hero?

Comment: Is the villain actually omnipotent? Or just so relatively powerful that the protagonist has no possibility of resisting? Is it God? Or is it Prof. Moriarity? If it's God, there is a biblical model in the book of Job.

Answer (score 4):

This is the premise of the short story ["I have no mouth, and I must scream."](https://wjccschools.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/01/I-Have-No-Mouth-But-I-Must-Scream-by-Harlan-Ellison.pdf) by Harlan Ellison.

You have a hidden complication in your question that makes it difficult to develop a story: the omnipotent quality of the antagonist and the realistic response of the protagonist are at odds.

Ignoring that aspect of your question, you have to define a goal for the antagonist and the protagonist. What does each individual want? Since the villain can, by definition, achieve any goal they want, for the story to have conflict the villain's goal has to be something they can only get from the protagonist, and also that it doesn't mean anything to the villain unless the protagonist gives it to them willingly -- again omnipotence means the villain can make the protagonist do anything. Whatever the villain wants must be something the protagonist is unwilling to give them. The protagonist must be willing to suffer and suffer and suffer rather than give in and give it to the villain. This means it is of the utmost importance to the protagonist.

Comment: It's definitely hard to create interesting conflicts for omnipotent characters. There aren't many stories about evil near-omnipotent beings that you can crib from (the film *Brightburn* and maybe the character Homelander in the series *The Boys* come to mind), but if you look at good near-omnipotent characters like Superman it will help see what limits they can face.

Answer (score 0):

Being able to do anything does not mean that the being is going to do. Take for example Gods in almost every religion, they can force humans to obey them, but they do not do it. In most religions they give humans the time and well then they judge them. **Which means the omnipotent beings have codes and self-forced-rules**.

Another way is to get the omnipotent being gets lost in the thoughts and doubts of the non-omnipotent character. Humans are filled with doubts and inner philosophy and ethical questions. Getting these self-doubt thoughts slowly injected into the mind of the omnipotent will make their power not full or useless or self-destructive. **We humans think that our mind/philosophy/ethics have gone beyond God's, and of that we are proud. Use that pride and for sure you will have your audience.**